# AWS / Second Instance always forwards to first Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subdomain

i am quite new two Amazon Web Services. For a client I intended to clone the whole project to a second instances for development purposes. I setup the second instance successfully with a separate IP which is then supposed to be reached through a subdomain.

Now the problem is that both IPs (as well as the main- and subdomain of course) always forward to the first instance - the main (live) page.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would guess that you have missed a setting in whatever it is that generates the "main page"

Comment: Without knowing a great deal more about the configuration of each instance and the infrastructure surrounding them, this is virtually impossible to diagnose.

Comment: Is there any specific information i could provide? As mentioned before - i am quite new to this.